# Regex capture group match lookup

Tags: java, regex, lexer, java-6

I have a regex with multiple disjunctive capture groups

```
(a)|(b)|(c)|...
```

Is there a faster way than this one to access the index of the first successfully matching capture group?

(matcher is an instance of java.util.regex.Matcher)

```
int getCaptureGroup(Matcher matcher){
    for(int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); ++i){
        if(matcher.group(i) != null){
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by faster.  You can make the code a little more efficient by using `start(int)` instead of `group(int)`

```
if(matcher.start(i) != -1){
```

If you don't need the actual content of the group, there's no point trying to create a new string object to hold it.  I doubt you'll notice any difference in performance, but there's no reason *not* to do it this way.

But you still have to write the same amount of boilerplate code; there's no way around that.  Java's regex flavor is severely lacking in syntactic sugar compared to most other languages.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. By faster I mean that the result is stored in an other structure than an iterative list and can be accessed < O(n) in terms of complexity. I suppose I have to copy the Matcher and Pattern code and tweak this myself.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the pattern is so:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
  String wholeMatch = matcher.group(0);
  String firstCaptureGroup = matcher.group(1);
  String secondCaptureGroup = matcher.group(2);
  //etc....
}
```

There could be more than one match. So you could use while cycle for going through all matches.

Please take a look at "Group number" section in javadoc of [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: This is not the answer.....he is asking the faster way than his current implementation.

Comment: That could be typo..... instead of  return i; that should be return matcher.group(i)..........also i am not the down voter too....

Comment: Actually I just return (and that's intended) the index of the ***first successfully matching capture group***

Comment: Then may be it would be easier to try to match by each group, as I see tag lexer. Like `if (string.matches("pattern1")) { //do something} elseif (string.matches("pattern2")) {//do something else}`. For me capturing groups are more useful for extracting data, but not for guessing which pattern matches :)

Comment: Imagine I have **`(abcdef0)|(abcdef1)`**, wouldn't it be more efficient to have only one compiled pattern?

Comment: It's an interesting question, you could do some benchmarks on that and post them here. [About microbenchmarks in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)